# managed query taking long time to execute, how to solve?

Tags: android

In my music player application, i want to display the albums list from artist. 
Please see my source code below.
The execution of first query for fetching artist is right, but when the second query is executed for fetching albums respect to a artist, its execution is right, it give the result, but it take long time for execution. How i decrease the execution time?

```
String[] columns = {android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Artists._ID,android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST};
cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Artists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columns, null, null, null);

int indexOfArtistId = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Artists._ID);
int indexOfArtistName = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST);
//int indexOfAlbumId = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID);
int count = 0;
for(cursor.moveToFirst(); !cursor.isAfterLast(); cursor.moveToNext()){

    artistIdArrayList.add(cursor.getString(indexOfArtistId));
    artistNameArrayList.add(cursor.getString(indexOfArtistName));

    String[] columnsAlbum = {

        android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID,
        android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
        android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION
    };
    String whereAlbum = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST_ID + "=?";
    String whereValAlbum[] = { cursor.getString(indexOfArtistId) };
    Cursor cursorAlbum = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, columnsAlbum, whereAlbum + ") GROUP BY ("+MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID, whereValAlbum, null);

    ArrayList<String> albmIdAList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> albmNameAList = new ArrayList<String>();

    int iOfAlbumName = cursorAlbum.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM);
    int inOfAlbumId = cursorAlbum.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID);
    int inOfAlbumMediaDuration = cursorAlbum.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION);

    for(cursorAlbum.moveToFirst(); !cursorAlbum.isAfterLast(); cursorAlbum.moveToNext()){
        if(Integer.valueOf(cursorAlbum.getString(inOfAlbumMediaDuration)) > 10000){
            albmIdAList.add(cursorAlbum.getString(inOfAlbumId));
            albmNameAList.add(cursorAlbum.getString(iOfAlbumName));
            //Toast.makeText(ArtistsGrid.this, ""+cursor.getString(indexOfArtistName)+" :: "+cursorAlbum.getString(iOfAlbumName), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: For one, why not use the other variations of getting data on the cursor, like getInt(), getLong() etc. Getting it as a string then converting it to an int is costly.

Comment: Try [profiling](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) your method